# How to split an Expression that creates anonymous types in C#

Tags: c#, lambda, expression, linq-expressions

I have a expression in C#

```
abc => new { abc.x, abc.y }
```

i want to break it down to

```
abc => abc.x
abc => abc.y
...
```

so i can loop through each argument.
Anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: What is the context? What do you mean by "break it down"?

Comment: Something like `foreach (var arg in ((NewExpression)myExpr.Body).Arguments)`?

Comment: If you're asking how to return multiple items instead of a single item, look at SelectMany()

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous declarations are just an abstraction for an anonymous type [generated at compile time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx).

You won't be able to generate them on the fly like you describe.

Comment: Well, you could consider them an abstraction over a delegate, which could simply point to a generated method on a generated class.

Comment: But the question doesn't ask how to generate new anonymous type at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why do you want to do this, but mellamokb comment shows the direction. The whole method could look something like this:

```
IEnumerable<Expression> GetExpressions<TParam, TResult>(
    Expression<Func<TParam, TResult>> expression)
{
    return ((NewExpression)expression.Body).Arguments
        .Select(a => Expression.Lambda(a, expression.Parameters.Single()));
}
```